# Converting Oracle SQL to SQL Server

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-server-2012

I'm looking into converting an Oracle query into SQL Server query and I am a little confused as I want to make sure I'm understanding it correctly...

Say I have a query..

```
Select t1.Name, t2.Address, t3.Num
From t1, t2, t3
Where t1.code = t2.othercode
  and t2.Id = t3.otherId
  and t3.Indicator = 'N'
```

Now the `FROM` statement - this means that they are all `INNER JOINED` automatically? but I am not specifying what `FIELDS` they are joined on? My question basically is, is the WHERE clause in Oracle what I should be JOINING on in my FROM part of the query as in:

```
SELECT t1.Name, t2.Address, t3.Num
FROM t1 
JOIN t2 ON t1.code = t2.othercode
JOIN t3 ON t2.id = t3.otherId AND t3.indicator = 'N'
```

Would the above 2 queries do the same?

I don't have exact data in Oracle as I do in SQL Server and I'm trying to make sure my logic is sound.

Thanks.

Comment: No, if you have a number of tables, comma-separated, in your `FROM` clause - they're by default producing a **cartesian product** - unless you define join conditions in the `WHERE` clause. Really - you should **avoid** comma-separated lists of tables in a `FROM` clause and use the **proper** ANSI/ISO SQL-92 JOIN as you show in your second example - that's the way to go, and has been for way over **25 years** now !

Comment: Comma joins aren't an Oracle thing specifically. As far as I know you can use them in any SQL database, if you really must. We have `join` clauses in Oracle too.

Comment: `AND t3.indicator = 'N'` really belongs in the `where` clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `join` query is equivalent to the version with commas.  The queries should be functionally equivalent (return the same result set).  I would actually expect them to produce the same execution plans.

That said, you should write the query using `join` in *both* databases.  That has been the preferred syntax for more than two decades (in general:  Oracle was a little late to the party).

And both databases should handle the query with commas -- databases do still support the archaic syntax.  So, you can test the version with `join` *in Oracle* and validate that it produces the same result set.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, yes that's what I did. As always thanks.